# DATEDIFF working on yyyymmdd format SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why the DATEDIFF accepts yyyymmdd format ? Isnt it only for yyyy-mm-dd format ?

The function DATEDIFF(datepart, start_date, end_date) is working fine when the dates are in yyyymmdd format e.g.

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, 20161201, 20161231);

It gives answer 30
```

and if you do  DATEDIFF(DAY, 20161201, 20161231) + 1 -- end date inclusive

```
It gives 31
```

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Actually, the SQL Server standard for date constants *is* YYYYMMDD, without the hyphens.  The hyphenated version works with almost all internationalization settings (there is one exception).  I prefer the hyphenated version because I'm a human and find it easier to read.

Comment: WOW..that is amazing...Thank you!!! If you post the answer, I will mark it as answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just curious.  What is the one exception?

Comment: The hyphenated version will not work properly with DATEFORMAT YDM and a datetime type.  It will work with other dateformats and other datetime types (date, datetime2, datetimeoffset).

Comment: It is not working in SQL 2012. Perhaps you used single quotes around the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a bit hard to tease out, but it is explained in the documentation, in the section ["Supported String Literal Formats for date"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx).

There are five sections on this (but the last two are API specific).  The first section is affected by internationalization settings and has a bunch of different formats.

The second is the ISO 8601 format.  I think the hyphenated format conflicts with the very last format in the first table ("yyyy dd mm" without the hyphens).

The final section has this informative line "A six- or eight-digit string is always interpreted as ymd".  Hence, 'YYYYMMDD' is always interpreted correctly.  Hence, this is the unambiguous format for date/time.

Note:  Because the functions you are using expect dates, if the integer works, then it is converted to a date using its string representation.  Normally, date constants should be in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its the sql server default format of dates but you can format your dates according to your requirements by following the link:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2012/format-function-vs-convert-function.aspx